# how to change d3.csv to d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

can any one tell me how to change the following d3.csv to d3.json

```
d3.csv("sp500.csv", type, function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);
      x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);
      x2.domain(x.domain());
      y2.domain(y.domain());

      focus.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "area")
          .attr("d", area);

      focus.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      focus.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);

      context.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "area")
          .attr("d", area2);

      context.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
          .call(xAxis2);

      context.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x brush")
          .call(brush)
        .selectAll("rect")
          .attr("y", -6)
          .attr("height", height2 + 7);
    });}
```

the above code is taken from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 I need to read the data from json file,

Comment: do you have `sp500.json` ready ? if you have then you can directly use `d3.json("path/to/file.json",  function)`. Ask server side to return data in JSON format

Comment: I have sp500.json ready... please let me know the function to be added at d3.json("sp500.json",function(?))

Answer (score 0):

Use d3.json function, rest all your code depend on structure of data returning by json file

```
d3.json("sp500.json", function(error, data) {
console.log(data);
//rest all your code depend on structure of data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; })));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) { return d.price; }))]);
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x brush")
      .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("height", height2 + 7);
});}
```

Refer https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests for documentation